# Store multiple values for a key in Collectors.toMap() in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

This is how my map looks like.

```
Map<String, String> maps = List.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Cat::getName, Cat::getNumber, (c1,c2) -> c1));
```

If I already have "Lucy, 101" in maps then I am unable to add another value corresponding to the name Lucy i.e "Lucy, 102". Is there any way to change the merge function [ (c1,c2) -> c1 ] so that I can have two values corresponding to a single key (Lucy) in my maps?

Comment: So if you do `maps.get("Lucy")`, which one would you expect to get? How about changing `maps` to a `Map<String, List<String>>` (in which case you'd use `groupingBy`)?

Comment: @Sweeper I want both the values to my key. Eg. maps.get("Lucy") should return both 101 and 102. Is there any way to store both the values without changing `maps` to a `Map<String>, List<String>> ?`

Comment: Would you accept joining the strings together (`"101 102"`) as "both 101 and 102"?

Comment: I was thinking of joining the strings only if I have no other options left

Answer (score 4):

By your requirement, in order to allow multiple values for the same key, you need to implement the result as `Map<String, Collection<String>>`.

In your case, you can merely use `groupingBy + mapping` collectors instead of `toMap` with the merge function:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> maps = List.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Cat::getName, 
            Collectors.mapping(Cat::getNumber, Collectors.toList())
        );
```

---

However, you may want to consider a merge function as joining strings:

```java
Map<String, String> maps = List.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Cat::getName, 
            Cat::getNumber, (num1, num2) -> String.join("; ", num1, num2)
        );
```

Then the map would contain "compound" values in the form of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Since the type of your map is `Map<String, String>`, it can only return *one* string. However, you expect to get *multiple* strings from `get`. You need to change the type of the map to e.g. `Map<String, List<String>>` or `Map<String, Collection<String>>`.

Then, you can use `groupingBy` like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = yourList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Cat::getName, // group by the name
    Collectors.mapping( // map each group of cats to their numbers
        Cat::getNumber, Collectors.toList() // collect each group to a list
    )
));
```

If you are okay with multiple numbers in the same string (e.g. `"101 102"`), you can use `Collectors.joining`:

```
Map<String, String> map = yourList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Cat::getName,
    Collectors.mapping(
        Cat::getNumber, Collectors.joining(" ")
    )
));
```

Comment: Okay. What if we don't look at the scenario of getting multiple Strings from `get`? I just want to store multiple values to a key. Is that possible?

Comment: @Meg What is the point of that, if you can't get it with `get`? Do you just want `values` to contain it?

Comment: And why don't you want to change the type of `maps`? This is beginning to sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to be honest. @Meg

Comment: yeah, that's true. Anyways, thank you for your help :)